# Как сделать библиотеку из проекта в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть небольшой проект, содержащий кодеки для аудио и видео.
Как из него сделать библиотеку, чтобы подключить к другому проекту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменить `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` на `apply plugin: 'com.android.library''`

Comment: это в настройках где-то?

Comment: @Александр, в `build.gragle`

Comment: изменил, а как дальше получить файл библиотеки?

Comment: @Александр а зачем? просто подключи как исходники. Ну или просто сбилдить и результат будет по адресу `/libs/build/yourlib.aar`

Comment: Или если нужен jar - он после билда будет по пути: `\build\intermediates\bundles\debug\classes.jar` ну или `release` вместо `debug`

Comment: @anber, спасибо )